# Which is the event used to add javascript method into a checkbox while loading the pdf form?

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have an Editable Pdf form in my application. In that form, I had added a checkbox. On the checkbox mouse up event, I had added a javascript to set the read-only property of a button to false when the checkbox is checked and the read-only to true when the checkbox is unchecked. My issue is When I load the pdf form in the Adobe reader, the javascript that I had added to the checkbox mouse up event not working. Is there any other event that we can be used for adding script while loading the pdf form.

Which is the event that can be used to invoke a javascript method in pdf form loading??

Comment: Some references: 1. https://forums.adobe.com/thread/797188
2. https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the code within the .checked function of checkbox

```
if(document.getElementById('IdOfTheCheckBox').checked) {
//your code goes here
}
```

Comment: I need an Adobe javascript method which can be invoked during the pdf form loading.

Comment: sorry my bad. i just understood